# how to use IConsoleLineTracker for reading console in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have developed a plugin in which a java application is launched.In the console log of this application i want to be notified when new lines added.I have searched internet and found org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers extention point.I have used it like below.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers">
  <consoleLineTracker 
     id="com.plugin.util.MyConsoleTracker"
     class="com.plugin.util.MyConsoleTracker"
     processType="MyProcessType">
  </consoleLineTracker>
</extension>
```

Then in my java code i have launched application like below.

```
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_CLASSPATH, classpath);
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH,false);
config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_MAIN_TYPE_NAME,MAIN_CLASS_NAME);
config.setAttribute(IProcess.ATTR_PROCESS_TYPE, "MyProcessType");
ILaunch launch = DebugUITools.buildAndLaunch(config, ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE,new NullProgressMonitor());
```

After these, i can launch my application successfully however my class com.plugin.util.MyConsoleTracker is never called.I cant see any error log either.
can anybody please tell me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For an example you can see how it is made in m2e-core:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.launching/src/org/eclipse/m2e/internal/launch/MavenConsoleLineTracker.java

and

http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.launching/plugin.xml

Methed of YourConsoleLineTrackers should be evoked each time when a new line is showed up in console. Inside Line Tracer you have to distinguish to which process this line belongs to.

Marek

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.